# Django-Grappelli import error "No module named urls"

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I'm trying to give Grappelli a spin but I can't seem to get past the very basic "Getting started" tutorial on their site. Note: I'm using Django 1.6.0.

I've added 'grappelli' on my settings.py and correclty set-up the static files stuff.

On my urls I've added:

```
url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
```

And I'm getting

```
ImportError at /grappelli/
No module named urls
```

On Django's shell however, I am able to import grappelli, just not the urls:

```
>>> import grappelli
>>> print grappelli
    <module 'grappelli' from '/.../grappelli/__init__.pyc'>
>>> from grappelli.urls import urlpatterns
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named urls
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: did you add `grappelli` to `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Yep, right before django.contrib.admin

Comment: I use grappelli, and I dont see any issues in my django shell. can you see where you are importing `urls` where name is not defined ?

Comment: Hi karthikr, I'm sorry, I didn't quite get your request. I only have a problem with grappelli urls though, as soon as comment that line from my urls.py everything works well.